# mongodb $regex not working with $options x

Tags: mongodb

I have models collection of documents in mongodb atlas. This is how document looks.

```
{
 name: "Iphone 11 Pro Max",
 description: "",
}
```

I have a value like "Iphone11ProMax", that I retrieved from the URL params. Now I want to query the above document with this value. But wasn't able to because the value I have doesn't have spaces and I can not manually insert spaces since params changes. so I tried using $regex operator like this

```
const {name} = req.params;
const pattern = new RegExp(name);
Model.findOne({name: {$regex: pattern, $options: 'x'}});
```

Since 'x' option ignores the any whitespaces, I thought it might work but it did not. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `"$regex"` [`"$options"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#mongodb-query-op.-options) `"x"` only ignores whitespace in the **regex pattern**, not the target string.

There are several options to query your collection with the value retrieved from the URL.  One option is to programmatically place `/s*` between each character in this value to use as your `"$regex"` pattern.  After transforming this value, the query could be like this.

N.B.:  You may or may not need to "escape" `\` in the `"$regex"`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "name": {
    // put "\\s*" between every character in regex
    "$regex": "I\\s*p\\s*h\\s*o\\s*n\\s*e\\s*1\\s*1\\s*P\\s*r\\s*o\\s*M\\s*a\\s*x"
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-Up9dcSgkZy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I actually found a work around by adding a key in the model that stores the name value without spaces , then I can query this value.